# Add rewrite rule for shop pagination

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, pagination

I want to know how can I change my shop pagination. Actually I have like this link: /watches/page/2 but I want to change it to: /watches/page=2

I don't know how, if i have to do something in the functions.php or in the htaccess.

Please can u help me?

Answer (score 1):

This actually requires a whole different structure. The page=2 is actually a value send to a script, meaning that the page will load dynamically. watches/page/2 is usually a static page. 
I'm not an expert, don't necessarily take my answer for good. Just building reputation.